# Semi Eulerian graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I do not understand how it is possible to for a graph to be semi-Eulerian.

For a graph G to be Eulerian, it must be connected and every vertex must have even degree.

If something is semi-Eulerian then 2 vertices have odd degrees. But then G wont be connected.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't $G$ be connected? Look at the path graph:

$$ - - - - - -$$

Comment: The definition of a connected graph I have is "there is a path between every pair of distinct vertices". In your diagram there is no path between for example the 2nd and 5th "dash"

Comment: @user204450 There is no EDGE, but there is a path: 2nd to 3rd to 4th to 5th.

Comment: oh ok, I think I understand fully the definition of connected graph now. There does not have to be an edge, there can be paths.